# what is difference between TerritoryManagement1.0 and TerritoryManagement2.0 in sfdc

Tags: territory-management, territory

What is difference between TerritoryManagement1 and TerritoryManagement2 in sfdc.
why we go for TM2.0, is there any advant1ges compared to TM1.0.
Please give any suggessions.